# Is Sp_DropServer needed at the end of a query?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I want to run a query with a linked server (**sp_addlinkedserver**). I would, however, not want the server to "stay linked" after the execution. Do I have to execute an **Sp_DropServer**? (Or is linking per query?)

(I'm running it from within a C# application. Perhaps this matters?)

Comment: Are you saying you have a number of queries or is this a one time thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the sp_addlinkedserver procedure does not make a, let's say, "keep alive" connection. When you execute that stored procedurem you are "mapping" an external server (sql server and other data sources) to your managed server.

Sp_dropserver is useless IMHO, since we're speaking about configurations. Additionally, if you're running in a high concurrency environment, every account that executes that query, can create and destroy a "server setting".

I suggest to create your linked server (following the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479(v=sql.110).aspx)) and then to use it when you need. You can also point to it using [SYNONYMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544(v=sql.110).aspx).
You C# application can use a t-sql statement with synonyms.